# Oracle access from iOS

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, oracle, ipad

I'm developing an iPad app that needs read-only access to an Oracle database.

Is there any way to do this? As far as I can see, the only options are using OCI, which requires a prebuilt binary in the form of the instant client (and not built for ARM), or OJDBC drivers. Both of these seem to be out of the question.

In my research I have discovered that libmysqlclient compiles for arm with minimal tuning. This is a stretch, but is there any possible way to use this to my advantage?

I have seen [this product](http://odbcrouter.com/ipad) providing odbc connectivity through the use of a Windows gateway machine using the ODBC client libraries, but this solution really isn't an option for me at the present time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very bottom, there are only two libraries for accessing Oracle:

1. The OCI binary library.
2. The Java OJDBC Jar file.

All other libraries (such as ODBC, ADO.NET) build upon one of these libraries (usually on OCI).

There's no OCI library for the iPhone (or any ARM architecture as far as I know) and there's no Java VM to use OJDBC. So you cannot directly connect from the iPhone to an Oracle database.

So whatever your solution will be, it'll require an intermediate server (or gateway).

Comment: I have since realized that there's a way to access Oracle natively: using `gcj`

Answer (score 1):

While I did end up using an intermediary server... I have since realized that this isn't strictly necessary. Direct access should be obtainable by using the OJDBC drivers directly on iOS using gcj to compile them for ARM. Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you could use JNI for communication to and from. Hope this helps anyone who comes here :)

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to an Oracle database from iOS is not possible as of this moment. Exchanging data with an Oracle database by means of web services is fairly simple. You can use APEX for this, lean and mean.