# How do I connect to an Oracle database using Objective-C (iPhone application)?

Tags: objective-c, oracle

I am new to Objective-C and xCode and have tried to find example code on how to connect my iPhone application to an Oracle database (remote server).  Does anybody have advice, or better yet, an example?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle access from iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594751/oracle-access-from-ios)

Answer (score 3):

You would not want to connect to a database using the App. You should connect with a webservice which is connected to the database.

Data being transferred from the iDevice to whatever location is possibly being captured. Always take the safe approach