# Using OCI for ARM7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, oracle, arm

Am trying to use Oracle OCI for an iOS Application, as my manager recommended me to try this for an internal application am coding for my firm. I downloaded the OCI for Mac OS X and included it in an XCode project and tried to build the project. Landed with the following warnings:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JYDw-CZXR30/UVqZ1xY68UI/AAAAAAAAEn8/pBz7-JneXWk/s1413/Screen%2520Shot%25202013-04-02%2520at%25202.16.00%2520PM.png

Thoughts on how to go about? Am I taking the right steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can tell, Oracle doesn't distribute iOS compatible libraries for OCI at this point.  The libraries you downloaded [from their "Mac OS X" download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) are meant for 32-bit and 64-bit MacOS (and decidedly ***not*** ARM7) architectures. You'll also see other architectures listed on those Oracle download pages, but nothing exclusively Mobile.

[Other people have asked this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594751/oracle-access-from-ios).

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree, Michael. Sounds like it's not a good thing pursue. Thank you.